# Connection from a Java program to a SQL Developer database

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to access to a Oracle database (SQL Developer) from a Java program. I never used JDBC before.
Here is what i wrote:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
String url = "jdbc:odbc:host_name:port:database_name";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, passwd);
```

I got an error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]
      Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Host name, port, DB name and logins are good.
Is this driver OK to communicate with SQL Developer ?

I don't know what to do, 
thanks for helping !

Comment: There is no such thing as a "SQL Developer database". To connect to an Oracle database (for which SQL Developer is usually used), use the Oracle JDBC driver, not the (deprecated) ODBC bridge.

Comment: Start here for possible answers: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oracle+jdbc+connection

Comment: If you just google, you will know how to connect to oracle DB. Do some research before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

Comment: `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` has been deprecated for several years, you should use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` instead

Comment: I was using oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver and its working fine.. Not aware of the updated one..

Comment: You haven't needed to explicitly load the driver like this for a long time, ever since the service provider mechanism introduced - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC driver `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` is *bridge* driver that wraps an ODBC driver as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/bridge.doc.html).

SQL Developer is an Oracle tool that acts as an IDE against the Oracle database.

To connect Java to an Oracle database you should obtain the Oracle JDBC driver and ensure the jar is on your classpath (as described in the documentation for [`java.sql.DriverManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html), forcing the class to be loaded is no longer necessary).

The important bit is the connection string, which in its simplest form for Oracle should follow the structure:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:port/service
```

Where:

- host: the hostname of the machine running Oracle
- port: the port that Oracle is listening for connections on
- service: the database instance to connect to

The full docs are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/urls.htm#BEIJFHHB).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. The connection string i used is: jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:service and it works, thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

for Oracle you can use ojdbc

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

for SQL Server u can use jtds

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
```